# Why is my value showing as None, when returned from a function?

Tags: python, list

My code:

```
def inverse(A,R,C):
    D,E=[],[]
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            D.append(A[j][i])
        E.append(D)
        D=[]
 
    Column_major(E,R,C)


def Column_major(A,R,C):
    s=0
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            if i==j:
                s+=A[i][j]
         

    #print(s)        #<-- shows the correct output
    return s         #<-- shows it as None


T=int(input())
A,B=[],[]
c=1
for i in range(T):
    R,C=input().split()
    R,C=int(R),int(C)

    for j in range(R):
        for k in range(C):
            B.append(c)
            c+=1
        A.append(B)
        B=[]

    s=inverse(A,R,C)
    print(s)
    A,c=[],1
```

In the above given code, my `s` value shows as `None` when I run it from the *main()* method, but when I print it inside the function *Column_major()*, then it shows the correct output. Why is it showing `None` when I return the value?

Comment: Because you're not returning anything from `inverse` function.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `return` in the `inverse` function when you call `Column_major()`:

```py
def inverse(A,R,C):
    D,E=[],[]
    for i in range(R):
        for j in range(C):
            D.append(A[j][i])
        E.append(D)
        D=[]
 
    return Column_major(E,R,C)  # return here
```

Comment: But I'm only returning the value from the `Column_major()` function, not from the `inverse()` function.